# Specific Virtual Host not responding

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a bare-bone CentOS 5.6 server, running apache, and serving two websites, http://soccernmoore.com and http://evosoccerprograms.com, all of a sudden, im having trouble connecting to the evosoccerprograms.com domain, the website is awfully slow and might take a couple of minutes to loadup. I checked everything, double checked the server status and all is fine. So my question is how to troubleshoot something like that, i have no idea where to start.

Apache Vhosts Dump:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server soccernmoore.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/soccernmoore.conf:26)
         port 443 namevhost soccernmoore.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/soccernmoore.conf:26)
         port 443 namevhost evosoccer (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl (8:11:14, 3:48 PM).conf:81)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server soccernmoore.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/soccernmoore.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost soccernmoore.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/soccernmoore.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost evosoccerprograms.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:994)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Are those sites dynamic? If yes - start by adding some static html files and see how fast are they loading. If the speed is ok then you should start checking your scripts.

Comment: Can you paste output of # apache2ctl -t -T DUMP_VHOSTS ?

Comment: @risyasin just added it

Comment: @Glueon static files are served very fast, the website is running modx ill try to troubleshoot

Comment: Vhost configuration for port 80 seems to be ok. but you have a problem for ssl configuration (or just a paste problem) first apache is not expecting correct domain name for https of evosoccerprograms.com probably a typo in configuration file in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl --- (filename seem to be corrupt or modified) evosoccer written instead of   evosoccerprograms.com.

Comment: for being slow. you may want to try apache's loglevel statement. like 
LogLevel notice or LogLevel debug. if it seems too complicated/cryptic you can disable apache modules one by one so you can diagnose which module has problem.